# Publish Error via Azure Data Factory after Terraform Deployment Pointing to existing GitHub Repo

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, terraform-provider-azure

I have an error below when I tried to publish from Azure Data Factory after It is deployed via Terraform.

> **Publishing error**: Invalid references or dependencies found. This is
> likely due to publishing outside of Git mode or editing and deleting
> linked services in other branches. To recover from this state, please
> refer to the errors below and our Git troubleshooting guide
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-factory/source-control#stale-publish-branch

The repo settings in the Data Factory is below:

[image]

The Data Factory is created and deployed by Terraform. All pipelines in JSON files created in the DF are stored in a GitHub repo like below:

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory" "data-factory" {
  name                = "data-factory"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.data-factory.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.data-factory.name
  github_configuration {
    account_name = "xxxx"
    branch_name = "main"
    git_url = "https://github.com/xxxx/azure-data-factory-etl-demo"
   repository_name = "azure-data-factory-etl-demo"
    root_folder = "/"
  }
```

I publish from Data Factory after the deployment **without** making changes to the repo and anything in Data Factory.

I tried both Options 1&2 in the link below, but it is **still not working.**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-factory/source-control#stale-publish-branch

Any idea?

**Update:**

The Github repository is `public`

Data Factory in Github for `Authorized OAuth Apps` is below (GitHub -> Settings -> Applications -> `Authorized OAuth Apps`)

[image]

I am able to create a new branch in my Github repo from Data Factory, which means it has write permission.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

The ***format of `git url` you are providing is wrong*** . It ***should be either `https://github.mydomain.com` if you using GitHub Enterprise or  `https://github.com` if open source repo***.

**So , Applying the above I tested the below code in my environment :**

```
provider "azurerm"{
    features{}
}
resource "azurerm_data_factory" "data-factory" {
  name                = "ansumandata-factory"
  location            = "eastus"
  resource_group_name = "ansumantest"
  github_configuration {
    account_name = "AccountName"
    branch_name = "main"
    git_url = "https://github.com"
   repository_name = "azure-data-factory-etl-demo"
    root_folder = "/"
  }
}
```

[image]

***After Deployment I opened `Data Studio` and it prompted me for `Github login` . After logging in and providing permissions , I created a `Integration Runtime` and `published` it which was successful.***

[image]

---

**Update :**

I tried the code you are using from the ***[`GitHub link`](https://github.com/gersta/az-data-factory-terraform-demo/blob/main/main.tf)*** you provided. It's also working properly as well . I am also using ***`2.93.1 azurerm provider`*** .

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed the github reference in Terraform based on your advice. But it is still not working. Very strange. The example is from this https://medium.com/twodigits/deploy-your-azure-data-factory-through-terraform-2a9c2bd2d75d

Comment: code example is available on that link

Comment: I copied all files from the link into my repo I created in my own GitHub account. `version = "~>2.0` is mentioned on the file https://github.com/gersta/az-data-factory-terraform-demo/blob/main/main.tf. But I can see it is terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.93.1_x5.exe under VS Code.

Comment: Thx for helping. Please see my update on OP. On Azure support, I am unable to create a support ticket because I am not a paid subscriber for the support. Any way I can get help from them? It might be an Azure issue.

Comment: I have Visual Studio Subscription monthly credits.

Comment: ok i was using paid one let me try once from visual studio subscription as well

Comment: working fine in my visual studio subscription as well

Comment: @Pingpong, you can reach out to MS support here in Microsoft Q & A:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/index.html

Comment: thanks. That forum seems quiet. I posted another issue there one month ago and has no answer. anyway, I posted it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/712379/publish-error-via-azure-data-factory-after-terrafo.html.